# $F:\mathcal{B}G \rightarrow Vect_{\mathbb{F}}$

Tags: limits, category-theory, functors

Let $F$ be the functor $F:\mathcal{B}G \rightarrow Vect_{\mathbb{F}}$, where $Vect_{\mathbb{F}}$ is the category of vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Prove that $\lim F \cong V^G$ is the fixed point subspace of the $G$-action.

I have proven in a different exercise that there is a one-to-one correspondence between functors from $\mathcal{B}G$ to $Vect_{\mathbb{F}}$ to vector spaces with a G-representation. Also, I know that for any functor $G: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow Set$ with $Obj(\mathcal{D})$ a set, then $\lim G$ exists and

$\lim G \cong \big\{(x_d \in G(d))_{d \in Obj(\mathcal{D}}):G(f)(x_d) = x_{d'}, \; \forall f \in \mathcal{D}(d,d')\big\}$

Although we are considering $Vect_{\mathbb{F}}$ instead of $Set$, it seems like this result can be applied somehow to prove the desired result. However, it may also be necessary to compute $\lim F$ by using the definition. I am stuck in that case as well.

Comment: So you already have $\lim (G \equiv UF)$?

Comment: That description of the limit works just fine for vector spaces (of course, you need to realize the *set* thus described is actually a *subspace* of the product). If you plug the definition in, you should get $V^G$ pretty directly. Have you tried it? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: @Thorgott What exactly do you mean by "subspace of the product"? Also, just to be clear, when I said "by using the definition", I was referring to trying to compute $\lim F$ from the universal property.  I did try, this, but it is not obvious to me in that case how $\lim F \cong V^G$.

Comment: @AHusain I'm not quite sure what that is, so my assumption is no.

Comment: You're right, using the definition was not so bad!

Comment: Forgot to say with $U$ being forgetful